# Taking data from a text file and putting it into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need some help taking data from a .txt file and putting it into an array. I have a very rudimentary understanding of Python, and I have read through the documentation sited in threads relevant to my problem, but after hours of attempting to do this I still have not been able to get anywhere. The data in my file looks like this:

> > 0.000000000000000000e+00 7.335686114232199684e-02
> >
> > 1.999999999999999909e-07 7.571960558042964973e-01
> >
> > 3.999999999999999819e-07 9.909475704320810374e-01
> >
> > 5.999999999999999728e-07 3.412754086075696081e-01

I used `numpy.genfromtxt`, but got the following output: `array(nan)`

Could you tell me what the proper way to do this is?

Comment: What is your code so far? Why leave it out???

Comment: How is the data in the input file formatted? Is it two numbers per line, as you suggest here? Do you want all of the numbers stored in the same array, or do you want to parallel arrays?

Comment: Its two columns of data (two numbers per line) and it's a time series so I would guess parallel arrays - unless of course my logic is flawed. You'll have to excuse my ignorance here. Coding is  clearly not my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - using `numpy.genfromtxt` does the right thing even with blank lines.

Perhaps share your code.

```
In [289]: numpy.genfromtxt('afile')
Out[289]:
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   7.33568611e-02],
       [  2.00000000e-07,   7.57196056e-01],
       [  4.00000000e-07,   9.90947570e-01],
       [  6.00000000e-07,   3.41275409e-01]])

In [290]: !cat afile
0.000000000000000000e+00 7.335686114232199684e-02

1.999999999999999909e-07 7.571960558042964973e-01

3.999999999999999819e-07 9.909475704320810374e-01

5.999999999999999728e-07 3.412754086075696081e-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.loadtxt()` is the function you are looking for. This returns a two-dimenstional array.

Comment: Your answer should just answer the question specifically. If you need more information, comment on the original post.